# How to give selected dates result back in java?

Tags: java, date, datetime, calendar

Actually in my java program User give `Start Date` and `end Date` ex:2012-12-01 and 2012-12-30 and Now we can give result back to between dates of Start date and end date.

If we want every day we can give using the following code...

```
List<Date> dates = new ArrayList<Date>();
     DateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-mm-dd");
    String str_date ="2012-12-03";
    String end_date ="2012-12-06";
    Date startDate = (Date) formatter.parse(str_date);
    Date endDate = (Date) formatter.parse(end_date);

    Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
    Calendar cal1 = Calendar.getInstance();
    cal.setTime(startDate);
    cal1.setTime(endDate);
    int i=0; // use this for alternative date print
    while (!cal.equals(cal1)) {

        cal.add(Calendar.DATE, 1);
             System.out.println(cal.getTime()); 

        }
```

But it is not the case the Problem is User want only `Monday,sunday` dates in his Start date and end Date then How to check that one....

```
For Ex: String userWeeks="SUNDAY,MONDAY";
```

This is User String then How to Compare `Calendar` Dates into this `userWeeks` string.

First thing we can Split the String `userWeeks.split(",")` then we get separate `SUNDAY   MONDAY`

```
So How to compare This String into Calendar?
```

Comment: your problem statement is not clear. can you please specify clearly, ur desired input and desired output

Comment: We are given output back to between dates of Start date and end date only containing MONDAY and SUNDAY..

Comment: And what information do you want from `Calendar`?

Comment: i want only between dates form Start date and end date from Calendar..

Comment: Do you mean , you need all days which are either sunday or monday between a given startdate and enddate?

Comment: yes... exactly ...thank for your replay..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally i'm thinking this way is there any issues of my code Please discuss me..

```
    import java.text.DateFormat;
import java.text.ParseException;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Calendar;
import java.util.Date;


public class SimpleDateFormatClass 
{
    public static void main(String args[]) throws Exception
    {
         DateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-mm-dd");
            String str_date ="2012-12-01";
            String end_date ="2012-12-10";
            Date startDate = (Date) formatter.parse(str_date);
            Date endDate = (Date) formatter.parse(end_date);
            Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
            Calendar cal1 = Calendar.getInstance();
            cal.setTime(startDate);
            cal1.setTime(endDate);
    while (!cal.equals(cal1))
    {       
                cal.add(Calendar.DATE, 1);      

         String days="Fri,mon,tue";
          for (String retval: days.split(","))
            {
        SimpleDateFormat sdf= new SimpleDateFormat("EEEE");
        Date date1= sdf.parse(retval);

              if(date1.getDay()==cal.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK))
                  {
                       System.out.println(cal.getTime());
                  }
           // System.out.println(date1);
           }
    }//While
    }//Main
}
```

Answer (score 1):

add if condition in ur loop

```
 while (!cal.equals(cal1)) {
          cal.add(Calendar.DATE, 1);
          int dayOfWeek = cal.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK);
          if((Calendar.MONDAY==dayOfWeek)||(Calendar.SUNDAY==dayOfWeek)){
            System.out.println(cal.getTime());
          }
        }
```

Comment: Ok it is correct... but i want to check 'userWeeks' String in my Program it is contain MONDAY or SUNDAY or any of Seven days in that time what we do.. so i want to check Calendar dates in my 'userWeeks' String

Answer (score 1):

check like this

```
int day=cal.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK);
if(day == Calendar.SUNDAY)
{
//it is sunday
}
```

for checking with strings

```
HashMap<String,Integer> daysOfWeeks=new HashMap<String,Integer>();
daysOfWeek.put("SUNDAY",new Integer(Calendar.SUNDAY));
//and the rest
```

then

```
String day=//user input;
Integer i=daysOfWeek.get(day)
if(i!=null)
{
if(i==Calendar.SUNDAY)
{
//it is sunday;
}
}
```

Comment: thank for your replay... but i want to check Start date and end date by using my own string userWeeks so in that time what we do..

Comment: you will have to create a hashmap if possible

Comment: thankyou for your ans... yes i want exactly this one but days like 7 if we check 7 days with if condition the code was very large and also user given days with a string like repeatDays = " MONDAY,TUESDAY,WEDNESDAY,THURSDAY,FRIDAY,SATURDAY,SUNDAY"; so again 7 loops so is their any better solution..

Comment: well the values of Calendar.SUNDAY , Calendar.MONDAY etc are in sequence like Calendar.SUNDAY = 1 ; and so on. if you can use these info to create your loop. I leave the rest to you. try printing the values on console